# Can't use cout/endl when extern "C"

Tags: c++, extern

I hope someone can help me on this small problem as I'm getting no where at all. Firstly, heres the code:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
#include<hidsdi.h>
#include<SetupAPI.h>
}

int main()
{
    int iQuit;

    cout << "Testing Program" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It won't let me use the std stuff (ie cout, cin, endl etc). It will only allow me to use it when I take out all the extern "C" code... Why is that? And is there a way around this?

EDIT: Sorry, forget to tell you the exact error: It says identifier "cout" is undefined

Thanks

Comment: I would not use std globally anyway. You could move the using namespace std; inside the main.

Comment: What purpose does `extern "C"` serve here?

Comment: Because cout is not a C keyword but a C++ singleton instance. You can't access C++ objects from plain C code (although it's possible the other way around).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm learning to write a driver so I can do stuff with my devices like keyboards and mouses, so I'm using the WDK. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought you need to use extern "C" to use those header files?

Comment: Drivers are written in C and not in C++.

Comment: @David: Not necessarily.  But there is not `stdout` in the driver environment, so it makes sense that a C++ environment for driver development wouldn't provide `std::cout`.  This combination is, however, entirely appropriate for driver installers and other applications that detect installed hardware.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not necessarily, but in practice drivers are written in C. And I suspect this code was compiled as C, hence the error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If it was compiled as C, there would be a myriad of other errors. Unless you want to say the only difference are linker options (as in, the C++ stdlib isn't linked in).

Comment: In fact, none of the headers you use are appropriate for drivers.

Comment: @delnan If you take that file, give it a .c extension and throw it at the MS compiler, then the error matches that quoted in the Q.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK then. I would have suspected MSVC isn't *that* sloppy and doesn't parse files it decided are C files as C++, but apparently...

Comment: @delnan Now I'm not so sure. I saw the `std::cout` not defined error, but now I cannot repro.

Comment: @delnan Yes, you see that when you pass `main.cpp` to `gcc`. Very odd.

Comment: `Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought you need to use extern "C" to use those header files?` No, the convention is that `extern "C"` should be inside the header files so that the code is treated as C regardless of whether the person compiling the code is using C or C++. All you need to do is include the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the problem, I weren't adding the directories in the correct order in VC++ Directories.

The order should be:

```
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api
$(WindowsSdkDir)include
$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include
```

Don't know why it needs to be in this order, but it works now... Very strange...

Comment: Driver development is different. You should be writing code in C and you need to be careful which headers you include. Only include top level headers, e.g. ntddk.h

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the advice :). I know you kept saying write drivers in C, but is it really that bad to be writing it in C++??

Comment: Yes it is. What will you do when your C++ code raises an exception? That's not pretty in a driver. And there are other concerns. A websearch led me to this discussion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487420

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your compilation environment. There is nothing wrong with that code. It compiles and runs fine.

In a comment to the question you say:

> I'm learning to write a driver so I can do stuff with my devices like keyboards and mouses, so I'm using the WDK. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought you need to use extern "C" to use those header files?

In fact you should simply write code in C rather than C++ for driver development.

Comment: hmm... never knew you can compile the code as C :S. How do I check it out?? :S

Comment: How are you compiling it? What compiler, and what command line option? And what is the name of the file? In particular what is the extension.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studios 2010. The file name is Mainframe.cpp

Comment: @Danny if you rename the file `Mainframe.c`, it will automatically be compiled as C.